# What does this code do and why does it compile?

Tags: c++, oop, class, templates, gcc

I'm creating a Vector2 class in C++ as a template, and I want to define the `+` operator as a non-member friend function that can simply add two vectors.

This is the friend declaration inside my Vector2 template class:

```
template <class U>
friend Vector2<T> operator+(const Vector2<T> &lhs, const Vector2<T> &rhs);
```

This is contained in a `.hpp` file, but the implementation is in a separate `.cpp` file:

```
template <class T>
Vector2<T> operator+(const Vector2<T> &lhs, const Vector2<T> &rhs)
{
    return Vector2<T>(lhs.x_ + rhs.x_, lhs.y_ + rhs.y_);
}
```

This compiles without any warnings, however, it does not seem to work.

```
Vector2<int> v1(4, 3);
Vector2<int> v2(3, 4);

Vector2<int> v3 = v1 + v2;
```

When I try to compile the above snippet, GCC complains:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
prog.cpp:26:28: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘v1 + v2’

source/vector2.hpp:31:23: note: template<class U> Vector2<int> operator+(const Vector2<int>&, const Vector2<int>&)
source/vector2.hpp:31:23: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:26:28: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U’
prog.cpp:26:18: warning: unused variable ‘v3’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly define the `+` operator for my template class?

Comment: "This is contained in a .hpp file, but the implementation is in a separate .cpp file"... don't even try it. Put everything in a header. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Look again at the template parameters in the `friend` declaration. There's a mismatch there.

Comment: T != U. maybe pick one =P

Comment: I forgot to explain that, but I saw it in another SO answer, and basically I was asking why does it compile with different symbols (U, T), but not with the same ones (T, T).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template for the operator uses a parameter `U` that isn't used. The signature uses a `T` instead, that probably comes from a surrounding class template:

```
template <class U>
friend Vector2<T> operator+(const Vector2<T> &lhs, const Vector2<T> &rhs);
```

Because `U` isn't used, the compiler can't automatically deduce what type it should be and gives an error.

Use the template parameter consistently, put the definitions of any templates in the `.hpp` file, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler clearly states what the problem is. It cannot deduce the template parameter 'U'.
Your declaration(the .hpp file) is wrong. Should be

```
template <class T>
friend Vector2<T> operator+(const Vector2<T> &lhs, const Vector2<T> &rhs);
```

Comment: source/vector2.hpp:30:15: error: declaration of ‘class T’

source/vector2.hpp:12:10: error:  shadows template parm ‘class T’